# "Float:right" is not being applied on the submit button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float the submit button to the right in the form but I am facing problem the float is not being applied on the submit button `Login`. I have added some of server-side generated code.

**Code**

```css
      #login-form{
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #6B0000;
        color: white;
    
      }
    
      #loginButton{
        color: #6B0000;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        /*This one here does not work */
        float: right;   
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <h1>
                   Google Maps &amp; Yahoo Mashup
                 
            </h1>
        </header>
    
        <DIV id="content">
    <form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post" onSubmit='return false'>
    <input type="hidden" name="login-form" value="login-form" />
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Email</label></td>
    <td><input id="login-form:email" type="text" name="login-form:email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Password</label></td>
    <td><input id="login-form:pwd" type="text" name="login-form:pwd" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"  value="Login"  id="loginButton" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"  />
    </form>
        </DIV>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I set a colspan of 2 to the input button and gave its parent td a width of 100%, this along with the float right should shift it to the right.

```css
#login-form{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #6B0000;
    color: white;

  }

  #loginButton{
    color: #6B0000;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*This one here does not work */
    float: right;   
}   

  /* Make the input's parent td 100%, you may want
     a class here instead for browser support */
  td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <h1>
               Google Maps &amp; Yahoo Mashup

        </h1>
    </header>

    <DIV id="content">
<form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="login-form" value="login-form" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label>Email</label></td>
<td><input id="login-form:email" type="text" name="login-form:email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Password</label></td>
<td><input id="login-form:pwd" type="text" name="login-form:pwd" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!-- setting a colspan of two -->
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  value="Login"  id="loginButton" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"  />
</form>
    </DIV>

</body>
```

Comment: The problem for me is how to set the colspan value from JSF since the table, td, and tr tags are gernerated by the JSF.

Comment: Could you try overriding it with some JavaScript maybe something like this? 

document.querySelector('tr:last-child td:last-child').setAttribute("colspan", 2);

Comment: @MrAsker or simply add an empty `<td></td>` element before the one containing the submit button. But tables in general are a poor styalisation choice in 2002- I mean 2022.